# Chromium: how to block promoted content on Twitter? (uBlock Origin/uMatrix)

Tags: chromium, twitter, ublock-origin, umatrix

Using chromium on Debian with `uBlock Origin` and `uMatrix` how can we block Twitter's promoted content on my feed

Is it possible to achieve this through `uBlock Origin/uMatrix`? is there any alternative?

I have same problem on reddit.com, where I see "promoted" content when I visit from chromium.

With `Firefox`, on the other hand, where i am using `uBlock Origin` and `NoScript`, neither on Twitter, nor on reddit do I see promoted content.

Comment: I also have uBlock Origin installed on all my browsers, be them Firefox or Chromium-based (SlimJet in my case), but I've also installed NoScript to block some JS that pollutes websites in general, and Twitter in particular, and ViolentMonkey, that lets you install and run custom-made JavaScript scripts, of which there's a slew when it comes to customizing your Twitter experience. Among those scripts, I installed three: Mobile Twitter, New Twitter improvement and Fix Twitter layout. With those scripts plus uBlock Origin plus NoScript, I have zero "promoted" tweets in my TL in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

[uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) may be used with custom filter to block Twitter's Ads, here are some documentation/links on how to achieve that

[Link-1](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/aku0uo/cant_get_it_to_block_twitter_ads_promoted_tweets/), [link-2](https://malwaretips.com/threads/help-wanted-to-block-promoted-tweets-on-twitter.95123/), [link-3](https://gist.github.com/r00k/2f243be6c30325f6a9b31844d91fc910) and [link-4](https://flaviocopes.com/block-distractions-ublock-origin/)... you may for instance try adding the following on the custom filter list of uBlock Origin

```
twitter.com##.trends.Trends.module
twitter.com##.dashboard-right.dashboard
twitter.com##.module.DashboardProfileCard
!twitter.com##article:has-text(/Promoted|Gesponsert|Реклама|Promocionado|Sponsorisé/):xpath(../..)
twitter.com##:xpath(//span[(text()='Promoted' or text()='Gesponsert' or text()='Реклама' or text()='Promocionado'or text()='Sponsorisé']/../../../../..)
twitter.com##[data-testid="trend"]:has-text(/Promoted|Gesponsert|Реклама|Promocionado|Sponsorisé/):xpath(..)
```

This list is provided as an example.

Answer (score -1):

You could try an extension for this:

[Hide Twitter Ads - Block Promoted Tweets](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-twitter-ads-block-pr/bapmhjebfdbdpjjfafnkfidijkjlkakf),
described as:

> Free tool that hides promoted tweets while you browse Twitter.